# How to NOT send an email in ActionMailer when called from Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, sidekiq

I have a mailer:

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def send_something(user_id)

     return unless User.exists?(user_id)  #  <- the problem

     mail to: [...]
  end
end
```

Which is called from Sidekiq:

```
MyMailer.delay.send_something(id)
```

However if the user_id doesn't exist when the job is actually run, I want to just return and not send any email.  However Sidekiq doesn't like this and will raise an error (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2149).

How should I be doing this - is there a dummy/null ActiveMailer object I can return instead, perhaps?

Comment: Do you mean `return unless User.exists?(user_id)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the user exists before your create the job. Change the code to something like this:

```
MyMailer.delay.send_something(user.id) if user.persisted?
```

Furthermore you might want to check if the user still exists and wasn't deleted when the job runs later on:

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def send_something(user_id)
    user = User.find_by_id(user_id)

    if user
      mail to: [...]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: But I also need to check the user exists when the job runs - it may be that it runs 30 minutes or more later.

Comment: Hi - I don't see how that is different (I'll need to try it) - if the method doesn't return anything, the Sidekiq mailer is going to throw.